# Proof of corollary to Noether's Bound

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces

In Larry Smith's "Polynomial Invariants of Finite Groups" the following corollary (2.4.3) to Noether's Bound is stated without proof.

Noether's Bound: Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of a finite group $G$ and $H \leq G$ a subgroup of $G$. If $|G:H|!$ is invertible in $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{F}[V]^H$ is generated by elements of degree at most $m$, then $\mathbb{F}[V]^G$ is generated by elements of degree at most $m \cdot |G:H|$.

Cor: Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional representation of a finite group $G$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$. If $|G|! \in \mathbb{F}^\times$, i.e. $\mathbb F$ has characteristic zero or the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}$ is greater than $|G|$, then $\mathbb{F}[V]^G$ is generated by at most $\binom{\text{dim}_{\mathbb{F}}(V) + |G|}{|G|}$ elements of degree at most $|G|$.

How does this binomial coefficient arise?

Comment: Problem has been solved with two simple combinatoric results: Let k be a field, let $S = k[x_1,.... , x_n]$, $V = \sum_i x_i$, and let $S(m)$ by the space spanned by the monomials in $S$ of degree exactly $m$. Then (i) dim$_k (S(m)) = \binom{n+m-1} {m}, \ \forall m$.
(ii) $\sum_{i-0}^m \text{dim}_k S(i) = \binom{n+ m} {m}, \ \forall m$.